# Cannot Create or Modify pgpass.conf file in %APPDATA%\postgresql directory

Tags: windows, postgresql, database-backups, pgagent

So, I want to backup my database using the pgagent.

OS: Windows 10 (64 Bit)

I found out that pgagent is not installed in my environment.

So, I upgraded my pgAdmin to V4.3 and with that I am trying to install pgagent via Stackbuilder's edb_pgagent_pg13 option. The exe is downloaded on my system but when I install it, I get this error:

[image]

Then, I saw that there is no folder called postgresql in my APPDATA folder so I created one.
"C:\Users\Harshad\AppData\Roaming\postgresql" and then again run the edb_pgagent_pg13.exe

I am still getting the same error.

now, either I don't know how to create the pgpass.conf file or I dont know how to correctly create it.

These steps I followed are:

1. Creating the postgresql folder in my APPDATA folder
2. Running the edb_pgagent_pg13.exe as admin
3. Creating a blank pgpass.conf file in
   "C:\Users\Harshad\AppData\Roaming\postgresql"

On starting Stackbuilder again as an admin, I chose just the pgagent option but it gives me an error saying incorrect system username and password. It is required for the installation" When I did not get an option to enter credentials.

What should I be doing correctly to get pgagent which will allow me to create and schedule backup jobs?

Edit: Added OS information

Comment: There is no version 4.3 of PostgreSQL

Comment: Apologies, The SQL version is 13, The pgAdmin is 4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you installed PostgreSQL it used 'postgres' Windows account. You need to install pgAgent using this same account.

1. Start a command prompt and execute 'runas /user:postgres cmd.exe' to run the CMD as the correct user.
2. Run the pgAgent installation file from that CMD. In my case that was 'D:\Downloads\edb_pgagent_pg13.exe', in your case it's wherever you specified it to be.

That is what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when installing pgAgent, and it came down to the [Windows Password Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/password-policy).

In the final installation step, you are asked to provide an OS account for the service. By default, it uses "postgres", which is the account created by PostgreSQL. In my case, I didn't have an account named "postgres", suggesting that PostgreSQL might not always create this account during installation. This might be version-specific behavior (I used PostgreSQL 13 and 15).

If the account isn't present, the installer will create it. I ran into a hurdle here: my Windows Server 2019 had the ["password must meet complexity requirements"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/password-must-meet-complexity-requirements) policy enabled. The password I provided didn't fulfill these requirements, leading to a failure in account creation and the subsequent error you mentioned.

For those in a similar predicament, here are a few validated solutions:

- Use a password complying with the complexity requirement during installation.
- Disable the complexity requirement policy (although this isn't advisable).
- Rather than allowing the installer to create a new account, supply the credentials of an existing one.